# Motobecane Sprint Retro Fixie

Tags: touring

Question for rebicycling a Motobecane Sprint Blue.  I have a desire to rebicycle this Motobecane Sprint into a semi retro style with the orginal theme.  In short i would like to purchase the same Motobecane headset, use the Sakae Alloy grill stem, Rigid Chrome 27x1 ¼ rim, but with a single hub.  I want to use wood handle bars and a few brooks accents such a pedal boot with leather straps and a B17 saddle.

How do I identify which headset will fit this Motobecane (1970s) frame? Will the Weinmann 730 side pull fit a 700C if I shouldn’t use 27x1 ¼? Will I have room for fenders (wooden) on both the front (¼ diameter) and rear (½ diameter)?

Is the diameter of the seat post 25.4 x 200 an indicator of the size for the Sakae Alloy Stem and the type of bottom bracket.  I know the rear gap for tire is 126mm.

I am ordering this item from eBay so i would like to get as much before it arrives to that I don’t have to wait for pieces.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Hi Jessie, I'm wondering how this project went for you...